# Swiple photo inside the content div rather than opening in gallery mode

Tags: jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I am planning to use photo Swipe like the iOS facebook app. Which allows to scroll the image with in the content and when we click it open in gallery.  Some thing similar to http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/touchslider/examples#ex-2 but when we click i need to open the gallery view of photo swipe.

kindly advice me how to proceed about this.

Answer (score 0):

Wanns try this? This one is for mobile gallery.

DEMO http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html

WESITE http://www.photoswipe.com/